# SQL select rows having count > certain number

Tags: mysql, sql

I don't really know how to search for this, probably it's quite easy to do it, but I don't know how to do this.
I have a SQL table:

```
| c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 |
 data data data data data
```

So I've 5 columns, and now I want to select the rows with only the following (c1, c2, c3) where that row appears more than 5 times in the table
Something like this:

```
  Select c1, c2, c3 
  From table
  having count(*) > 5 and (all in that count, all rows must have the same values on c1, c2, c3)
```

Can only do this with basical sql queries. Functions, declarations and etc are not allowed.
Don't really know if i'm explaining myself well.

Comment: you should write up an example of your dataset and your expected result, that would help a bunch.

Answer (score 2):

Not absolutely sure I understand, but my guess would be

```
select c1, c2, c3
from <yourtable>
group by c1, c2, c3
having count(*) > 5
```

Comment: No, I don't want the row where all value area equal. I want the distinct count of rows, where the row 1 is equal to row 2.

Comment: @Elsendion or just remove the where clause

Answer (score 0):

This query will return all records from your original table whose `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` combined values appear in duplicate *more* than 5 times.  I also included the actual count in the result set.

```
SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t1.c4, t1.c5, t2.cardinality
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT c1, c2, c3, COUNT(*) AS cardinality
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY c1, c2, c3
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 5
) t2
    ON t1.c1 = t2.c1 AND
       t1.c2 = t2.c2 AND
       t1.c3 = t2.c3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just treat c1,c2,c3 as a single string c1+c2+c3:

```
SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM table WHERE
c1 || c2 || c3 IN (
  SELECT c1 || c2 || c3 FROM table
  GROUP BY c1 || c2 || c3
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 5);
```